# How to determine if a buffer will respond to outline-mode commands

Tags: outline-mode, outline

I'm [hacking together an extension](https://github.com/abingham/outline-toc.el) which will display a sidebar with an outline of whatever document you're working on. It was initially written to support writing in markdown-mode, but the technique I'm using (which might be bone-headed) relies on using outline-mode commands like `outline-hide-body`. As such, the extension should, I think, work for any mode for which these commands have an effect.

So my question is: is there a way to determine if outline-mode commands - and specifically `outline-hide-body` - are properly defined for a given buffer?

Right now I just rely on a list of major-modes (e.g. org-mode, markdown-mode) for which I know these commands work. But this seems like a relatively weak approach since it ignores e.g. outline-minor-mode which I should probably check for as well. So before I go down the path of trying to enumerate the the major and minor modes I can work with, I thought I should see if there's a better way.

Comment: As you said, check if outline-minor-mode is on. I doubt (but can't say for sure) many (if any) major modes are "implemented on top of Outline mode" (as org-mode docstring says).

Comment: Unfortunately that seems insufficient. For example, `describe-mode` doesn't list `outline-minor-mode` for markdown-mode (in my nearly stock spacemacs config). Or am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Comment: `markdown-mode` does not use `outline-minormode` but handles outlining itself.

Comment: Right, but functions like `outline-hide-body` work properly in `markdown-mode`. I think this is because `markdown-mode` defines `outline-regexp`.

Comment: You might consider looking at `navi-mode`.  You might be able to build your package on top of it and save yourself a lot of code.  :)